# How to get pinch, zoom, and rotate actions of pan gestures in swift with single finger or button, for details image is attached

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, transform, uipangesturerecognizer

Pan gestures are new to me, so apologies if question is confusing but Here is the image attached for clearing the question

[image]

I got multiple guides but all are using minimum 2 fingers. I want to use bottom right button to resize and rotate this text view/Label/view
Any guide or reference link will be appreciated

Comment: Hi did you get a result?

Comment: There was a library I found and used for this. I will share you that link, I need to look back in my source code, Will take a little while

Comment: Hi, so I make some research about this case and decided to share it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use 3 different GR, like pan, rotate, and scale.

But after research, I've found out that, when you make for example zoom, you automatically make really small dragging with your fingers, so at the same time you can get rotation event from corresponding GR, it could make many corner issues, when you have conflicting GRs.

So as at seems to me the best option is used
pan gest with one finger for moving
and use rotation and scale gests for scale and rotate.